# Discord Bot commands stop working after implementing reply function

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm very new to programming, but managed to get a very trivial fun bot working for a discord server. It listens to commands such as help and 8ball, but I also wanted it to respond to certain messages.

When I try to make the bot send a message after a specific message has been detected, it works, but all other functions stop working. When I remove the code for the reply function, everything works again. I assume it has something to do with the if statement and that it might need something like a return of pass, but I can't figure it out.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if 'bad' in message.content.lower():
        if 'bot' in message.content.lower():
            await message.channel.send('testmessage1')

    if 'good' in message.content.lower():
        if 'bot' in message.content.lower():
            await message.channel.send('testmessage2')
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your bot doesn't have a prefix? I mean the code you are using doesn't show that it runs with a prefix.

Comment: @BhavyadeepYadav `on_message` events do not need a prefix.

Comment: But how are you even executing this? I know it doesn't but how do you tell your bot to do this?

Comment: @BhavyadeepYadav The commands aside from the reply function do have a prefix, %.

Comment: @BhavyadeepYadav if I input the codesnippet above in the file, whenever someone in discord sends a message containing the words ''bad bot'' next to eachother, it automatically sends a reply

Comment: Oh! So you are doing that...

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński You absolute legend! That's what did the trick. Time to learn about coroutines I guess. Thanks!